# Replace items in list, python

Tags: python, replace

I have a list of strings like this:

```
Item_has_was_updated_May_2010
Item_updated_Apr_2011
Item_got_updated_Sept_2011
```

I want to iterate through the list of string and update the last 2 parts of the string. The month and the year. The rest of the string I want to remain the same. The month and year will be taken from variables I have set earlier in my script, so let's call the month x and the year y.

My approach is to:

1. Iterate through the list of strings
2. Split each string by "_"
3. Replace the last 2 items
4. Join the items back together with the replaced items

The month and year will be taken from variables I have set earlier in my script, so let's call the month x and the year y.

If anyone can suggest a an approach, it is appreciated.

Comment: What are you asking for exactly?  You've outlined a process that sounds reasonable, have you tried implementing it?

Comment: Lists in python an immutable, you can't change them.<br>
However you can copy them to a new list and in doing that make changes.

Comment: Lists are mutable. Strings are immutable though.

Answer (score 9):

You can do it without regular expressions by using `str.rsplit`:

```
yourlist = [s.rsplit('_', 2)[0] + '_' + x + '_' + y for s in yourlist]
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/WcvKY)

---

If you want to use formatting instead of string concatenation, try this:

```
yourlist = ['{}_{}_{}'.format(s.rsplit('_', 2)[0], x, y) for s in yourlist]
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/j9zDF)

Comment: Could also do `'_'.join(s.split('_')[:-2] + [x,y])`

Comment: @NiklasB.: +1 Yeah that works too. It's slightly more concise. It does some unnecessary splitting and joining compared to using `rsplit`. Probably not a huge issue considering the size of the example strings though.

Comment: I think it might even be faster than the string concatenation (which needs to create a new string 4 times) The `format` approach is of course okay as well :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you really need 're'.
You could use something like this:

```
m="dec"
y=2012
l=["Item_has_was_updated_May_2010",
    "Item_updated_Apr_2011",
    "Item_got_updated_Sept_2011"]
r=[]
for s in l:
    t=s.split("_")
    r.append("_".join(t[:-2])+"_%s_%s"%(m,y))
```

Comment: The `r = []; for s in l: r.append(...)` pattern is exactly what list comprehensions are good for :)

Answer (score 2):

```
lst = [
   'Item_has_was_updated_May_2010',
   'Item_updated_Apr_2011',
   'Item_got_updated_Sept_2011',
]
month='Sep';year='2012'
for s in lst:
        list=s.split('_')
        list[-2:]=(month,year)
        r=''
        for a in list:
                r=r+"%s_"%a
        r=r[:-1]
        print r
```